# Airflow ORM query optimization

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, airflow

I am using `AirFlow` to schedule jobs, however it becoming slower than before, especially for `task_stat` method in `views.py`, I have more than 400 dags and there are 3 millions rows in table `task_instance`.
I have to wait for more than 40 seconds to get the response of `task_stat` now, is there any ways to optimize this method?

The `union_all()` of `RunningTI` and `LastTI` is the slowest one, and if I remove `RunningTI` and keep `LastTI` only when union the result, I could get the response in 5 seconds, but `RunningTI` is necessary for front end to show detail info.

Does it possible to optimize this query? The database is MySQL.

the task_stat method:

```
@expose('/task_stats')
@login_required
@provide_session
def task_stats(self, session=None):
    TI = models.TaskInstance
    DagRun = models.DagRun
    Dag = models.DagModel

    LastDagRun = (
        session.query(DagRun.dag_id, sqla.func.max(DagRun.execution_date).label('execution_date'))
            .join(Dag, Dag.dag_id == DagRun.dag_id)
            .filter(DagRun.state != State.RUNNING)
            .filter(Dag.is_active == True)  # noqa: E712
            .filter(Dag.is_subdag == False)  # noqa: E712
            .group_by(DagRun.dag_id)
            .subquery('last_dag_run')
    )
    RunningDagRun = (
        session.query(DagRun.dag_id, DagRun.execution_date)
            .join(Dag, Dag.dag_id == DagRun.dag_id)
            .filter(DagRun.state == State.RUNNING)
            .filter(Dag.is_active == True)  # noqa: E712
            .filter(Dag.is_subdag == False)  # noqa: E712
            .subquery('running_dag_run')
    )

    # Select all task_instances from active dag_runs.
    # If no dag_run is active, return task instances from most recent dag_run.
    LastTI = (
        session.query(TI.dag_id.label('dag_id'), TI.state.label('state'))
        .join(LastDagRun, and_(
            LastDagRun.c.dag_id == TI.dag_id,
            LastDagRun.c.execution_date == TI.execution_date))
    )
    RunningTI = (
        session.query(TI.dag_id.label('dag_id'), TI.state.label('state'))
        .join(RunningDagRun, and_(
            RunningDagRun.c.dag_id == TI.dag_id,
            RunningDagRun.c.execution_date == TI.execution_date))
    )

    UnionTI = union_all(LastTI, RunningTI).alias('union_ti')
    # if I remove RunningTi in union_all(), and change line below to
    # UnionTI = union_all(LastTI).alias('union_ti'), it could save a lot of time

    qry = (
        session.query(UnionTI.c.dag_id, UnionTI.c.state, sqla.func.count())
        .group_by(UnionTI.c.dag_id, UnionTI.c.state)
    )

    data = {}
    for dag_id, state, count in qry:
        if dag_id not in data:
            data[dag_id] = {}
        data[dag_id][state] = count
    session.commit()
```

The related models:

```
class DagRun(Base, LoggingMixin):
    """
    DagRun describes an instance of a Dag. It can be created
    by the scheduler (for regular runs) or by an external trigger
    """
    __tablename__ = "dag_run"

    ID_PREFIX = 'scheduled__'
    ID_FORMAT_PREFIX = ID_PREFIX + '{0}'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dag_id = Column(String(ID_LEN))
    execution_date = Column(UtcDateTime, default=timezone.utcnow)
    start_date = Column(UtcDateTime, default=timezone.utcnow)
    end_date = Column(UtcDateTime)
    _state = Column('state', String(50), default=State.RUNNING)
    run_id = Column(String(ID_LEN))
    external_trigger = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    conf = Column(PickleType)

    dag = None

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('dag_id_state', dag_id, _state),
        UniqueConstraint('dag_id', 'execution_date'),
        UniqueConstraint('dag_id', 'run_id'),
    )


class TaskInstance(Base, LoggingMixin):
    __tablename__ = "task_instance"

    task_id = Column(String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    dag_id = Column(String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    execution_date = Column(UtcDateTime, primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(UtcDateTime)
    end_date = Column(UtcDateTime)
    duration = Column(Float)
    state = Column(String(20))
    _try_number = Column('try_number', Integer, default=0)
    max_tries = Column(Integer)
    hostname = Column(String(1000))
    unixname = Column(String(1000))
    job_id = Column(Integer)
    pool = Column(String(50))
    queue = Column(String(50))
    priority_weight = Column(Integer)
    operator = Column(String(1000))
    queued_dttm = Column(UtcDateTime)
    pid = Column(Integer)
    executor_config = Column(PickleType(pickler=dill))

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('ti_dag_state', dag_id, state),
        Index('ti_dag_date', dag_id, execution_date),
        Index('ti_state', state),
        Index('ti_state_lkp', dag_id, task_id, execution_date, state),
        Index('ti_pool', pool, state, priority_weight),
        Index('ti_job_id', job_id),
    )

class DagModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = "dag"
    """
    These items are stored in the database for state related information
    """
    dag_id = Column(String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    # A DAG can be paused from the UI / DB
    # Set this default value of is_paused based on a configuration value!
    is_paused_at_creation = configuration.conf\
        .getboolean('core',
                    'dags_are_paused_at_creation')
    is_paused = Column(Boolean, default=is_paused_at_creation)
    # Whether the DAG is a subdag
    is_subdag = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    # Whether that DAG was seen on the last DagBag load
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    # Last time the scheduler started
    last_scheduler_run = Column(UtcDateTime)
    # Last time this DAG was pickled
    last_pickled = Column(UtcDateTime)
    # Time when the DAG last received a refresh signal
    # (e.g. the DAG's "refresh" button was clicked in the web UI)
    last_expired = Column(UtcDateTime)
    # Whether (one  of) the scheduler is scheduling this DAG at the moment
    scheduler_lock = Column(Boolean)
    # Foreign key to the latest pickle_id
    pickle_id = Column(Integer)
    # The location of the file containing the DAG object
    fileloc = Column(String(2000))
    # String representing the owners
    owners = Column(String(2000))
    # Description of the dag
    description = Column(Text)
    # Default view of the inside the webserver
    default_view = Column(String(25))
    # Schedule interval
    schedule_interval = Column(Interval)
```

The link to github: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/views.py

Comment: did u resolve this? my taskinstance table has 2.8million rows and the task_stats icons won't load at all. It also seems scheduler is broken with tasks stuck in scheduled state for more than 10hrs. i am on airflow 1.10.3

Comment: Have you tried pagination? The query to check task_status cost a lot of time, I only search the task_status in the current page, and it becomes better, the other way is to move some not used records in task_instance to another table.

Comment: do i sense an auto-purge taskinstance table PR ? :)

Comment: I think it might be better if you have communicated with the users before you do this, I received some complain after I have moved records 3 monthes ago in task_instance to a backup table, since there is no task state info in WebUi for the records you moved, and someone might relay on it. There is an idea is to modify the views.py and read the records in the back up table, but I am stucked in other problems and not start this at all.